# Changing location of Android SDK when Android Studio or InteliJ IDEA launches SDK manager

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, sdk

Please note, this question is not about how to add a new SDK location to a project or the default for that for new projects.

On Windows I have moved the location of the Android sdk folder. I can start the SDK manager by running the exe in the root of the new folder.

I would like to be able to launch the SDK manager from the tool bar of IDEA. I can't find where to change the setting IDEA uses for the location of the SDK manager. It still runs the one at the old location. I renamed the old folder hoping IDEA would ask for the new location, but IDEA just fails (silently) to launch the SDK manager.

Once everything is working correctly I will delete the old SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that I can answer you with Android Studio as it us based on IDEA ? In my Android Studio 1.3, there is a way to change Android Sdk location in the IDE. In settings/Appearance&Behavior/System settings/Android SDK.

If I'm wrong, another tip, you can use mklink. In cmd :

```
mklink /j %appdata%/Local/Android/sdk your/new/sdk/path
```

It will create a file to replace your old sdk and it will redirect file request from your old sdk to the new path

Comment: I had expected Android Studio to be the same as IDEA, however that setting is not present. I was aware of the mklink option (junction point) and I think I may well have to fall back on that.

Comment: If I change the name of my SDK, Android Studio ask for the new path. It changed the value in multiple files so there is no simple config file to change